# How can I run my frontend code (react) and backend (node) concurrently while in different repositories?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-fullstack

My client code and server code are not in the same folder. I know that if I want to run backend and frontend together I can install and use concurrently library, however, every example to this i can find is always where client and server code are in same project folder so I can run something like that:

```
"start": "node index.js",
"client": "npm run start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run start\" \"npm run client\""
```

my project structure is like this:

```
myGreatApp
/src
/node_modules
....
```

my server side code is in another folder:

```
myGreatApp-server
/models
/controller
/node_modules
...
```

How can I do that? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as these two folders share the same parent folder,
i.e:

```
root
/myGreatApp
/myGreatApp-server
```

you have to only navigate yourself out of your current repo and inside of the other one.

Your server-side package.json should look like this:

```
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node index.js",
"server": "nodemon index.js",
"client": "cd ../ && npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
```

And your client-side package.json should look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
```

Then you can simply run `npm run dev` and they'll both run concurrently.